# running subprocess with combined cd and pwd

Tags: python, shell, command-line, subprocess, pwd

I run subprocess in jupyter to get the core path.
I have to go one folder up and then call pwd

Running:

```
import subprocess
mypath=subprocess.run("(cd .. && pwd)")
```

leads to a "No such file or directory: '(cd .. && pwd)' error.  I guess the cd calls a directory call.

Can you help me out?

Comment: BTW, `subprocess.run(['pwd'], cwd='..', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True).stdout.rstrip('\n')` is another way to get where you're going. Still less efficient than using the `os`-module tools, but not as inefficient as spinning up a shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frame challenge: `subprocess` is the wrong tool for this job.

```py
import os.path

mypath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
```

...is both faster and portable to non-UNIXy operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

for a single shell command (where the arguments are not separated from the command), you need to set `shell = True` in `subprocess.run`. Do

```
subprocess.run("cd .. && pwd", shell = True)
```

and it will work

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, no subprocess or shell is required for this.

```
import os.path
os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0]
```